# File Upload to BIM 360 works in Postman but not with React JS

Tags: reactjs, postman, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

Hi I'm new to Autodesk Forge. I was following the tutorial to upload a file to BIM 360. The upload works when using Postman but I'm unable to view the file when I upload using React JS.

I'm using FileReader and reading file as BinaryString. Where token is the access token.

```
onInputChange(e){
    let files = e.target.files;
    let reader = new FileReader(); 
    reader.readAsBinaryString(files[0]);

    reader.onload = (e) => {
        const buffer = Buffer.from(e.target.result, 'base64');

        var myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
        myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

        var requestOpts = {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: myHeaders,
            body: buffer,
        };

        
        fetch('https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/
            v2/buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName'
            , requestOpts)
        .then(response => response.json())



    }
}
```

The file manages to upload but im unable to view it in bim 360. Image below.

[bim360 file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy2o8.png)

Comment: Did you follow all the steps described here to [upload a file to bim360](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/) ? You must create a version of your file after uploading it.

Comment: Hi Alex , yes I did and the upload works fine when I use Postman. I am able to create a new version of the file and successfully view the file. The problem comes to when I'm trying to upload the file using React JS.

Comment: So, I think you must take a look closer at your `FileReader` method or `Buffer.from` method. If you use `reader.readAsBinaryString` you could use `Buffer.from(<yourstring>, 'binary')`, alternatively you can use `reader.readAsDataURL` to get a **base64** string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution thanks to the suggestion in the comments. Had to change the FileReader method to

```
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(files[0]);
```

The documentation found in
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/src/api/ObjectsApi.js shows that the body has to be an array buffer.